# How to get the result without joining the three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, t-sql

I have a sql join  like

```
select B.Team,Sum(A.Quota) as Quota from TableA A 
inner join TableB B on B.code = A.TblCode
group by B.Team
```

which gives me result

### Team         Quota

Spare         5000

Grace         2000

Same way i have another sql join like

```
select B.Team, Sum(C.Revenue) As Revenue from TableC C
inner join TableB B on B.code = c.StaCode
group by B.Team
```

Result for the above sql is

### Team         Revenue

Spare        10000

Grace         12000

Is it possible to get the result like the below other than joining three tables?

### Team           Quota          Revenue

Spare         5000             10000

Grace          2000             12000

I tried joining three tables which gave me different result as there are duplicates in one of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could `JOIN` the two results like this

```
SELECT x.Team, X.Quota, Y.Revenue
FROM (select B.Team, Sum(A.Quota) as Quota 
      from TableA A 
          inner join TableB B on B.code = A.TblCode
      group by B.Team) as x
JOIN (select B.Team, Sum(C.Revenue) As Revenue 
      from TableC C
          inner join TableB B on B.code = c.StaCode
      group by B.Team) as Y ON X.Team = Y.Team
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use correlated subqueries to compute the values separately:

```
SELECT Team,
       (SELECT SUM(Quota)
        FROM TableA
        WHERE TblCode = TableB.code) AS Quota,
       (SELECT SUM(Revenue)
        FROM TableC
        WHERE StaCode = TableB.code) AS Revenue
FROM TableB
```

(This is the equivalent of LEFT JOINs, but I doubt that you'd want to drop a Quota/Revenue value if there are no matches for the other one.)